# Simple counting exercise

Tags: combinatorics

> A race is being organized in Konoha, opposing 4 of its ninjas to 6 of Suna's.
> 1 - Given that no two ninjas can finish at the same time, how many outcomes are possible if we only consider the villages, not the ninjas (K1 K2 S1 ... == K2 K1 S1 ...)?
> 2 - If we only care about the top three, how many outcomes are possible given the same condition as in (1)?

1 - We want to eliminate the duplicates village-wise. Possible outcomes = $\frac{10!}{4!6!}$.
2 - If the first to arrive is a Konoha ninja, then there are $2\times2$ outcomes. Same thing with the other ninja, so the total is = $2\times2\times2=8$.

I think that everything is correct. Do you see anything wrong?

Comment: This looks correct to me.

Comment: Looks ok to me as well.

Comment: thank you, both of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Community wiki post so the question can be closed.

Both of your solutions are correct.

What matters in the first question is which positions are occupied by which village.  There are $10$ positions, of which $6$ can be filled by ninjas from Konoha.  This can occur in
$$\binom{10}{6} = \frac{10!}{6!4!}$$
ways.

What matters in the second question is whether a ninja from Konoha or Suna finishes in each position.  There are  two possibilities for each of the three positions, so there are indeed $2^3 = 8$ possible sequences in which the ninjas from the two villages could finish.